# calculating a sum with two variables from user created output file

Tags: c++

I'm trying to figure out how exactly I'd use my output text file I created to be used to calculate the sums of both variables. My output text file is saving the information correctly, but I get 0 and 0 for my sums so it's not reading the information I think. Also, does the information I enter into the arrays only save into the text file? I need it only being saved into the text file so that the sum calculations are only receiving information from the text file

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include<iomanip>
#include <fstream>


using namespace std;

int main() {
int ItemNumber[2];
float price[2];
int sumnumber = 0;
float   sumprice = 0;
string myfile = "c:/Users/rz/Desktop/numbers.txt";

int count = 0;


ofstream outFile;
outFile.open(myfile);
while (count <= 1)
{
    cout << "enter a price" << endl;
    cin >> price[count];
    outFile << price[count] << endl;
    cout << "enter a item number" << endl;
    cin >> ItemNumber[count];
    outFile << ItemNumber[count] << endl;

    count++;
}

outFile.close();


fstream inFile;
inFile.open(myfile);
while (count <= 1)
{

    sumprice = sumprice + price[count];

    sumnumber = sumnumber + ItemNumber[count];
}
cout << sumnumber << endl;
cout << sumprice << endl;
system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Think what value count is at the last while().

Comment: ah okay that makes sense lol sorry

Comment: is this still only getting the information from the file in the second loop?

Comment: Even if you fix the count your 2nd while loop is wrong. It does not change count in the loop..

Comment: On top of that I am not sure why you open the file for reading at all.

Comment: I used i instead of count on the second while loop and added i++ inside the while loop

Answer (score 0):

At the end of the first loop:

```
int count = 0;
while (count <= 1) { ... count++ ... }
```

the variable `count` will be set to `2`.

Then, when you start the second loop:

```
while (count <= 1) ...
```

the condition is *already* false, hence the body of the loop will never be executed.

In order for this to work, you would have to reset count back to zero so that it runs through the items again. Or, better yet, leave `count` alone (since it indicates how many items were processed) and use *another* variable to got through them:

```
for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) { ... use i rather than count ... }
```